# OpenVPN Connect for ios can't parse my .ovpn file

Tags: openvpn

For a user who wants to use my OpenVPN server on a mobile device, I have created a .ovpn file with embedded/bundled keys and certificates. But when I try to import it in the iOS client, I get this error:

```
option <cert> was not properly closed out
```

But the tag is properly closed out, and so are the others. Reordering the elements in the config file didn't change the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration parser is very simple, it expects to see the exact tag string on one line and nothing else. Make sure there is no whitespace before or after the closing tag.

Comment: It was just a new line after the last tag caused this error for me.